# rails “undefined method” when invoking a helper method from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helpermethods

I want to get the gender of a person from a helper method like so:

**sportists_helper.rb**

```
def sportists_gender
  gender = self.gender

  if gender == "1"
    "Male"
  elsif gender == "2"
    "Female"
  end
end
```

and then print it out in a **view**: `<%= sportists_gender %>`, but this gives me `undefined method 'gender'` error, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have Person model. here is an example:

Helper:

```
def sportists_gender(person)
  gender = person.gender

  if gender == "1"
    "Male"
  elsif gender == "2"
    "Female"
  end
end
```

Call From View.erb:

```
 <% @person = Person.first %> // any object according to your view.
 <%= sportists_gender(@person) %> // display result.
```

Comment: And to clarify, the reason your original code crashes is because the helper doesn't know what `self` is; helpers don't somehow get access to the model object for free.

Comment: @Xeen, you may also want to rethink the design a bit. Would it make more sense to have this method in the Person model itself instead of a view helper?